# How to bind a helper stub to swagger-node with supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, proxyquire, swagger-node-express

I am using [Swagger Node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) with express and I initialized the skeleton project. `Swagger project create hello-world`

Then inside the `hello-world/api/controllers/hello_world.js` I added a small modification to require a helper `hello_helper.js` and call its function `helloHelper.getName()`.

```
'use strict';
let helloHelper = require('../helpers/hello_helper');
var util = require('util');
module.exports = {
  hello: hello
};
function hello(req, res) {
  var name = req.swagger.params.name.value || helloHelper.getName();
  var hello = util.format('Hello, %s!', name);
  res.json(hello);
}
```

hello-world/api/helpers/hello_helper.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {getName: getName};
function getName() {
    return 'Ted';
}
```

I would like to stub `helloHelper.getName()` to return `'Bob'` instead.
I can do so easily with:
`hello-world/test/api/controllers/hello_world.js`

```
// Create stub import of hello_helper
mockHelloHelper = proxyquire('../../../api/controllers/hello_world', { '../helpers/hello_helper': { getName: function () { return 'Bob'; } }
});
```

Using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) how can I make swagger recognize my stub?

EDIT: Thanks to help from the answer below this solution worked for me.

```
var app, getNameStub, mockHelloHelper, request;
    beforeEach(function (done) {
       // Create stub import of hello_helper
        mockHelloHelper = proxyquire('../../../api/controllers/hello_world', {
           '../helpers/hello_helper': {
               getName: function () {
                   return 'Bob';
               }
           }
        });
        app = require('../../../app');
        request = supertest(app);
        done();
    });
...
it('should return a default string', function(done) {
        request
          .get('/hello')
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            res.body.should.eql('Hello, Bob!');
            done();
          });
      });
```

Comment: Can you share the part where you are using supertest?

Comment: @TalhaAwan Added supertest part. thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize/require express `app` after you have proxyquired your dependency. Only then it can use your stubbed version of `getName`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    mockHelloHelper = proxyquire('../../../api/controllers/hello_world', {
       '../helpers/hello_helper': {
           getName: function () {
               return 'Bob';
           }
       }
    });
    // initialize/require your app here
    request = supertest(app);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!